# Pass value from textbox to controller in update function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a problem to pass textbox value to the controller where the update function does not work. This is my script.

```js
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
        var txtValue = $('#id').val();  
        var ddlValue = $('#start').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Booking/Update',
            data: { id: txtValue, start: ddlValue },
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
        })
    }
    else {
        revertFunc();
    }
},
```

And this is my controller.

```vb
Function Update(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
    If IsNothing(id) Then
        Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    End If
    Dim book As book = dbb.book.Find(id)
    If IsNothing(book) Then
        Return HttpNotFound()
    End If
    Return View("Index")
End Function

<HttpPost()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function Update(<Bind(Include:="id,start,end")> ByVal book As book ) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        dbb.Entry(book ).State = EntityState.Modified
        dbb.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
    Return View("Index")
End Function
```

The value should be passed to update method and being searched. If there is matched id, start value should be updated. But it does not. I do not see any error here. Can anybody please help

Comment: Your method is marked with `<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>` but your not sending a token so an exception is thrown (and look at your browser console and the error would be clear)

Comment: I have removed the code but its still doesnt work

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: There is no error. But the start value are not updated

Comment: And what is the point of the code in your GET method - you query the database to get a `book` but ignore it (you never return the model to the view). And your POST method makes no sense either - your have a `RedirectToAction()` but ajax calls never redirect! What are you actually trying to do here? And what is the value of `start` in the POST method?

Comment: In GET method, it searched for matching id in book table. Then it will pass the id to POST method where start value will be updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137909/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-hud).